# Disable "hide keyboard"-button

Tags: android, keyboard

As you perhaps know, the "back" - button on the Google Nexus 7 changes to a button, which hides the soft keyboard, if the keyboard is visible (see picture below).

[image]

But I want to disable this button, so the keyboard can't be hidden.
Can someone tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure why you would want to do that but you can try overriding the back press in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //your custom code here
}
```

You would need to check if the keyboard is visible. You can refer to the following links for that: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+check+if+keyboard+is+visible

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that's not exactly what i'm looking for. Although it disables the back-button, it doesn't disable the button wich hides the kexboard...